# VS Code on Mac OS X: Failed to start Jupyter in the environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Running Jupyter Notebook on the Terminal works:

```bash
(tf) jupyter-notebook
[I 17:50:59.285 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: ...
```

The notebook boots up on `http://localhost:8888/` and I can run each cell.

Running Jupyter Notebook cell by opening a `.ipynb` file on VS Code gives:

```
Failed to start Jupyter in the environment 'tf (Python 3.9.15)'. View Jupyter log for further details.
```

Log:

```bash
error 17:51:15.828: Error in execution (get message for cell) [Er [Error]: Jupyter server crashed. Unable to connect. 
Error code from Jupyter: 1
usage: jupyter.py [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]
                  [--paths] [--json] [--debug]
                  [subcommand]

Jupyter: Interactive Computing

positional arguments:
  subcommand     the subcommand to launch

options:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --version      show the versions of core jupyter packages and exit
  --config-dir   show Jupyter config dir
  --data-dir     show Jupyter data dir
  --runtime-dir  show Jupyter runtime dir
  --paths        show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable
                 format.
  --json         output paths as machine-readable json
  --debug        output debug information about paths

Available subcommands:

Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.
```

I have the following extensions on VS Code related to Jupyter Notebook:

- Jupyter
- Jupyter Keymap
- Jupyter Slide Show
- Jupyter Cell Tags
- Jupyter Notebook Renderers

Running the notebook on VS Code previously always worked. It worked yesterday. I have made 0 configuration changes since EXCEPT downloading necessary TeX extensions for PDF conversion. The same error occurs on every Conda environment, nor does it resolve when I restart my computer.

Comment: Will the same problem occur if extension TeX is disabled?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to start Jupyter Notebook Kernel in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75330032/unable-to-start-jupyter-notebook-kernel-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been solved on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12750).

The solution is to switch to the pre-release version.

Click the in the extension store **Switch to Pre-Release Version**:

[image]

If it still doesn't work, you can choose conda interpreter and retry.

Comment: This didd't work for me. A workaround is to open a jupyter-lab instance on the project folder and get the url with token and add it as an existing remote Jupyter Server in VS Code.

Comment: Exactly that worked for me. Installing pre-release was enough to fix this problem. Worked with system, conda and venv kernels. (MacOS 13.2)