# Failed to start the Kernel. Jupyter server crashed. Unable to connect. Error code from Jupyter: 1

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Being a student and working every day with VSCode and .ipynb files, I was very surprised to see that, from one day to the next, the following error appeared when I tried to run a cell on one of my notebooks.

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 

Jupyter server crashed. Unable to connect. 

Error code from Jupyter: 1
```

After having tried the different solutions proposed by other topics, uninstall and reinstall, check that no server was working on the same address, nothing happens, the error persists.

Comment: have the been any changes to the system ?  any further error messages ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I put the end of the error message here:
Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found. 
View Jupyter log for further details.

Comment: Which OS/distro?

Comment: I'm on MacOs Monterey v12.5

Comment: the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57983475/jupyter-server-crashed-unable-to-connect-error-code-from-jupyter-1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter server crashed. Unable to connect. Error code from jupyter: 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57983475/jupyter-server-crashed-unable-to-connect-error-code-from-jupyter-1)

Comment: i've already try to implement these solutions and it doesn't work. I have only one interpreter so is the one which is selected by default.