# error while trying to use jupyter in VScode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am trying to use jupyter notebook in VScode but whenever I run a code, I am getting an error message saying failed to start kernel. I have installed python, have installed required extensions like jupyter, python and few extras as well and I am running this on mac. I am able to run python code and getting proper output for that but jupyter notebooks is acting up for some reason. [Here is a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEHI5.png)

I am expecting the jupyter notebook to run seamlessly

Comment: There's a lot of results if you google your error - [Jupyter server crashed. Unable to connect. Error code from jupyter: 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57983475/jupyter-server-crashed-unable-to-connect-error-code-from-jupyter-1)

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

my guess would be that you didn't install jupyter library so try `pip install jupyter`.

and please try to google it, :)

[Failed to start the Kernel - Jupyter in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70506366/failed-to-start-the-kernel-jupyter-in-vs-code) 
[Jupyter server crashed. Unable to connect. Error code from jupyter: 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57983475/jupyter-server-crashed-unable-to-connect-error-code-from-jupyter-1)  *this is the same issue*